# Looking for chinese R/C car remote instructions translated

Tags: translation

I got my son a R/C car that has the instructions to pair the remote in the Chinese language. I tried many online tools to scan and translate the image, but to no success. Can anyone help?

[image: R/C controller instructions in chinese]

Comment: Try a translating service like https://www.reddit.com/r/translator

Comment: https://hinative.com try this,  I think you can get well translation there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just translate from @user6065's transcript: 
２.４G 遥控器使用说明 
 首次使用需对码，本产品有记忆功能，以后换电池无须再对码 
（１）长按＂M＂键３秒以上，直到第一颗LED闪烁 
（２）打开车身电源，第一颗LED变为长亮，对码成功 
（３）遥控器10秒钟无操作自动待机按任意键唤醒 
（４）按键说明：△前进▽后退◁︎左转▷右转S调速P刹车 
按"S"键设定车速，前进时１颗灯为低速，２颗灯为中速，３颗灯为高速，倒车时仅有中速一个档位 
 按"P"键保持刹车状态，指示灯全闪，再次按刹车键解除刹车

Translation: 
2.4G Remote Control Instructions 
You need to pair it the first time you use it, the product has a memory function, it is not necessary to pair it again even if the batteries are changed 
(1) Press and hold the "M" key for at least 3 seconds, until the first LED lights up. 
(2) Open the car battery compartment, if the first LED is lit up the pairing was successful 
(3) If the remote control is not used for 10 seconds it will go into standby mode, press any key to wake 
(4) △ = Forwards, ▽ = Reverse, ◁︎ = Left, ▷ = Right, "S" = Change speed, "P" = Brake 
Press "S" key to set speed, the first light is low speed, the second light is medium speed, and the third light is high speed; there is only medium speed when reversing 
Press "P" key to maintain braking, when braking all lights will be lit, press "P" key again to release brake

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

use online translators on ２。４G 遥控器使用说明
首次使用需对码，本产品有记忆功能，以后换电池无须再对码
（１）长按＂M＂键３秒以上，直到第一颗LED闪烁
（２）打开车身电源，第一颗LED变为长亮，对码成功
（３）遥控器１０秒钟无操作自动待机按任意键唤醒
（４）按键说明：△前进▽后退◁︎左转▷右转S调速P刹车
按S键设定车速，前进时１颗灯为低速，２颗灯为中速，３颗灯为高速，倒车时仅有中速一个档位，按P键保持刹车状态，指示灯全闪，再次按刹车键解除刹车